# Plantilla propia, crear dos idiomas

Tags: php, html

he creado una página web desarrollada por mi con, HTML, PHP, MYSQL, JAVASCRIPT. Nunca he tenido el caso de tener que hacer una en más de un idioma, y es por eso que no se como puedo hacer todo lo que tengo en 2 idiomas. Buscaba algún consejo de como programar eso.

---

***Después de hacer varias pruebas he conseguido hacer esto:***

A través de .htcacces compruebo la variable idioma

```
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+).html$ controlador.php?inc=$2&idioma=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+).html$ controlador.php?inc=$1&idioma=es [QSA,L]
```

Archivo controlador.php

```
// Primero averiguamos el idioma seleccionado.
if (isset($_GET['idioma']) && $_GET['idioma']!='')
   $idioma=strtolower($_GET['idioma']);
else
   $idioma='es';

// Cargamos el fichero de idioma. Por defecto español.
include_once "{$idioma}_traduccion.php";
```

Fichero es_traduccion.php

```
// Fichero de idioma español.
define('h1_Vende','Vende tu casa');
define('h2_Tasacion','Tasación gratuita');
```

Fichero en_traduccion.php

```
// Fichero de idioma ingles.
define('h1_Vende','Vende tu casa ingles');
define('h2_Tasacion','Prueba Ingles');
```

Me faltaria saber como hacer que las Banderas funcionen, tengo esto y lo ideal es que salga la bandera de españa predeterminada y cuando elijas una cambie el idioma. Pero en la barra solo se muestre el idioma seleccionado ya que ahora se me muestran las dos. Esto lo tengo de este modo.

```
 <li class="dropdown pull-right dropLang">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle-mio" data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
          <img src="images/lang/flag-es.png" />
          <img src="images/lang/flag-uk.png" />
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right coloDrop">
        <li class="active padDrop">
          <a href="#" class="aDrop">
            <img src="images/lang/flag-es.png" />
            <span class="marDrop">Español</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="padDrop">
          <a href="#" class="aDrop">
            <img src="images/lang/flag-uk.png" />
            <span class="marDrop">English</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

Ya me dais vuestra opinión.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero si tu sitio web no tiene mucho texto, puedes almacenar los textos en [constantes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php) así:

#### Archivo: es.php

```
define('INICIAR_SESION','Iniciar sesión');
define('REGISTRARSE','Registrarse');
define('BIENVENIDO','Bienvenido a mi sitio web');
// etcétera...
```

#### Archivo: en.php

```
define('INICIAR_SESION','Sign in');
define('REGISTRARSE','Sign up');
define('BIENVENIDO','Welcome to my website');
// etcétera...
```

#### Archivo: index.php

```
<h1><?= BIENVENIDO ?></h1>
```

Como puedes observar, tendrías que crear un archivo por cada idioma y ponerle el [nombre del idioma](http://utils.mucattu.com/iso_639-1.html). Cada uno de ellos debe contener las **mismas constantes** y con los **mismos nombres**, **cambiando únicamente el valor de la constante**.

Pero aún queda una cosa, y es incluir el archivo correspondiente al idioma seleccionado, y se puede hacer de varias formas:

#### Usando el atributo lang (ejemplo.com?lang=es):

```
if ($_GET['lang'] == "en") {
    require "directorio/del/en.php";
} else {
    require "directorio/del/es.php";
}
```

#### Usando las cookies

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] == "en") {
    require "directorio/del/en.php";
} else {
    require "directorio/del/es.php";
}
```

Ahora ya tenemos los 2 idiomas y un sistema para cargar el idioma adecuado, pero para que el usuario pueda modificar su idioma, hay que añadir un botón o algo similar que añada el parámetro a la URL o que crea una cookie con el valor solicitado.